# JS function with e.key === 'Enter' won't fire when in screenreader (NVDA ) browse mode

Tags: javascript, screen-readers, nvda

Keyboard ENTER on a button element will not fire the psydo code at the bottom, when NVDA screenreader is enabled and in browse mode. I already found some suggestion, but they do not cover my requirements:

- Add `role=application` --> The content is no longer read correctly by the screenreader.
- Switch to focus mode manual --> Yes, this works. But the button
  is to open a dropdown. So the user don't expect to have to
  switch into focus mode.

So I know that the NVDA screenreader "swallow" some of the keyboard events. But I don't know any work-around. Do you have any idea?

Thanks a lot :-)

// psuedo code

```
button.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    // code
  }
}
```

Comment: In javascript `KeyboardEvent.key` returns a number. Pressing Enter for instance returns `13`

Comment: @Michel No, [it does not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

Comment: The code works when NVDA is disabled or in focus mode

Answer (score 0):

Because screen readers like NVDA intercept / swallow some keyboard events (in browse mode), I'm using now the `click` event. This one gets fired even NVDA is enabled and in browse mode.

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // code
}
```