# Keyboard tabbing doesn't work when screen reader in enabled

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility, nvda

I'm working on a react project. I have a popup in which tabbing works fine when screen reader is not enabled. But as soon as you enable the screen reader(NVDA), the tabbing stops working and instead focus shifts to previous selected item when pressing tab.

Any idea why this strange behaviour when screen reader is enabled on the page.

Comment: without something to test against, no we don't have any idea . Can you recreate the problem in a simple fiddle / snippet for us to investigate? The only thing I can guess at is that you are using `float: right` or `flex-direction: column-reverse;` etc. and the screen reader is following the DOM order not the page order (and something in React is accounting for that). But that is a complete guess, this is not normal behaviour so it is something within your implementation.

Comment: Actually @GrahamRitchie it would be tough to recreate the problem in a simple fiddle as it's part of a larger project & has multiple dependencies to run. But I can explain the scenario. It'a task manager page. It tells you number of tasks you have on a day. On pressing enter key on the count, it should a dialog to show the detailed list of tasks. Instead the controls ignores the dialog & jumps to the next block.

Comment: Ah, you might need focus management then. If the modal dialog has a heading add `tabindex="-1"` to it and then add `headerElement.focus()` at the end of the function that opens it (or focus the close button). It is probably down to how the virtual cursor on the screen reader works. Bear in mind that modals require a lot of extra work for screen readers as they will not generally be navigating with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, so you need to make all other content inaccessible while the modal is open with `tabindex="-1"` on active elements and `aria-hidden="true"` on everything else.

Comment: I'm seeing different behavior mentioned here. Originally you said TAB didn't work when NVDA is running but in your comment you said you pressed ENTER on an element to trigger a dialog and the dialog wasn't working. I've **never** see the TAB key **not** work when NVDA is running. If you have `role="application"` on an element, then NVDA will allow all events to pass through to that element so maybe you have an event handler that is not handling the TAB event properly. If so, that would be a problem regardless of whether NVDA is running.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I got to root of it. Actually screen readers suppress some native javascript events.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181014/js-function-with-e-key-enter-wont-fire-when-in-screenreader-nvda-brows

In my case onKeyPress doesn't get fired at all when screen readers are enabled.
Is there any way to make it work with screen readers enabled.

I already tried the approach in the above given URL. It doesn't work in my case.